# What are electrolytes and why are they important?

Tags: nutrition

What are electrolytes and why are they important? What are they for?

You always hear about needing electrolytes when exercising, but what are they for?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> An electrolyte is any
>   substance containing free ions that
>   make the substance electrically
>   conductive.
>
> In physiology, the primary ions of
>   electrolytes are sodium (Na+),
>   potassium (K+), calcium (Ca2+),
>   magnesium (Mg2+), chloride (Cl−),
>   hydrogen phosphate (HPO42−), and
>   hydrogen carbonate (HCO3−). All known
>   higher lifeforms require a subtle and
>   complex electrolyte balance between
>   the intracellular and extracellular
>   milieu.
>
> In oral rehydration therapy,
>   electrolyte drinks containing sodium
>   and potassium salts replenish the
>   body's water and electrolyte levels
>   after dehydration caused by exercise,
>   excessive alcohol consumption,
>   diaphoresis, diarrhea, vomiting,
>   intoxication or starvation. Athletes
>   exercising in extreme conditions (for
>   three or more hours continuously e.g.
>   marathon or triathlon) who do not
>   consume electrolytes risk dehydration
>   (or hyponatremia).

[Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrolyte)